# use a for loop to add element in to the java.util.ArrayList,but the list's address of the reference always changing

Tags: scala

I have a strange problem when I use a for loop to add element in to the java.util.ArrayList , but the list's address of the reference always changing
Here is the code:

```
var curntRow: Row = null
var startTime: lang.Long = null
//this is the list
var standTime: util.ArrayList[Row] = new util.ArrayList[Row]()

for (row <- usersCoorOrderByTime) {
  if (curntRow == null) {
    startTime = row.getAs[lang.Long](2)
  } else if (!row.getAs[String](1).equals(curntRow.getAs[String](1))) {
    //And I use the method list.add() right here
    standTime.add(Row(row.getAs[String](0), row.getAs[String](1), row.getAs[DoubleType](4), row.getAs[DoubleType](5), curntRow.getAs[lang.Long](2) - startTime))
    startTime = row.getAs[lang.Long](2)
  }
  curntRow = row
}
```

And please see the pic that I debug below:
[addr is "7703"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdM3L.jpg)

Before get in the loop The list's addr is "7703"
When is get in the loop ,the address changes
[change to "11268"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhxf7.png)

[change to "11287"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLxRr.png)

The most strange things is when it end the loop, the address has changed back to where it was originally declared

[change back to "7703"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkeQq.jpg)

finally I get an empty ArrayList

Comment: Are you sure you are not watching two separate threads? And why is `standTime` a `var`? If you are not assigning to it, make it a `val`. That also makes sure that the object won't be replaced.

Comment: Those are not addresses, they are some kind of incrementing reference number generated for debugging. So this looks like a debugger question rather than a coding question.

Comment: Thx answer,I found that It's not really about the address(Neither var nor val worked ),should be other problem,by the way,the for loop parameter is a Spark Dataframe,Maybe here's the problem.

Comment: Conclusion, mutability and distributed computing are a bad idea. You do not even understand that for loop is executing in multiple machines at the same time, thus the different addresses. Also, why are you collecting the DF to a local collection? And why with a loop, spark already provides this method, and why to a Java collection if you are using Scala?

Comment: Next time you should try mentioning key words like Spark Dataframe and tagging same for viewers and for answer providers

Answer (score 0):

I found the error
the parameter of for loop is Dataframe, I should turn to Array or List then make for loop

Answer (score -1):

Try using Mutable ArrayBuffer. Below is a simple example. I hope it helps.

```
val x = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]()
x += "2"
x += "4"
println(x)
```

Comment: Thanks Answer,but it still not working,maybe the problen is not the variable